# Antlr4 .net does not rebuild the parser/lexer on a clean check-out

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, nuget, antlr4

I have a project which contains a small DSL which is built with [ANTLR4 for .net](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Antlr4). This project is only part of one branch of my repository. When I switch branches and clean my local working copy (i.e., doing `git clean -fdx` or trying to open a fresh clone of the repository), and then re-opening this project, Antlr does not re-generate the parser and lexer code, leading to compile errors. It only works after I uninstall and re-install Antlr4 into the project via the NuGet Package Manager Console.

I already installed Antlr4 support for Visual Studio.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not quite a solution, but a workaround: When I rename the .g4 files, and shortly after that, change back their names to the original ones, Antlr4 picks them up correctly again.